# User's mysql custom image and Minikube strange behavior

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, mariadb, minikube

Sup. I created my service, deployment and persistent volume claim so my mysql sholud work inside minikube, but it doesn't. I can't figure out why docker container outside minikube works fine, but when i try to use it inside minikube cluster my database purges somehow. Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk upgrade -a -U
RUN apk add mysql mysql-client openrc supervisor
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
COPY ./my.cnf /etc/
COPY ./secure_config.sh /root
RUN rc default
RUN /etc/init.d/mariadb setup
RUN /etc/init.d/mariadb start
RUN chmod 755 /root/secure_config.sh
RUN /root/secure_config.sh
RUN sed -i "s|.*bind-address\s*=.*|bind-address=0.0.0.0|g" /etc/my.cnf
RUN sed -i "s|.*bind-address\s*=.*|bind-address=0.0.0.0|g" /etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf
RUN sed -i "s|.*skip-networking.*|skip-networking|g" /etc/my.cnf
RUN sed -i "s|.*skip-networking.*|skip-networking|g" /etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf
COPY ./wpdb.sh .
COPY ./sql_launch.sh .
RUN chmod 755 /wpdb.sh
RUN chmod 755 /sql_launch.sh
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/
EXPOSE 3306
CMD /sql_launch.sh
```

wpdb.sh

```
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE wordpress;"
mysql -e "CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin';"
mysql -e "CREATE USER 'lchantel'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'lchantel';"
mysql -e "CREATE USER 'pstein'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pstein'"
mysql -e "CREATE USER 'admins_mom'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admins_mom'"
mysql -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '';"
mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'admins_mom'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456');"
mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'admin'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456');"
mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'pstein'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456');"
mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'lchantel'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456');"
mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin';"
mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

sql_launch.sh

```
#!bin/sh

rc default
chmod 777 /wpdb.sh && /wpdb.sh
rc-service mariadb stop
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

This is my mysql output within the container

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user FROM mysql.user
    -> ;
+-------------+
| User        |
+-------------+
| admin       |
| admins_mom  |
| lchantel    |
| mariadb.sys |
| mysql       |
| pstein      |
| root        |
+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.006 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

and this is my outputs inside minikube pod

```
# rc-status
Runlevel: default
 mariadb                                                                                                                                                                      [  stopped  ]
Dynamic Runlevel: hotplugged
Dynamic Runlevel: needed/wanted
Dynamic Runlevel: manual
/ # rc-service mariadb start
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/tasks: Read-only file system
 * Datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' is empty or invalid.
 * Run '/etc/init.d/mariadb setup' to create new database.
 * ERROR: mariadb failed to start
```

And so i guess problem is in yaml file in mountPath section of deployment. There're yaml files

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-mysql
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 500Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/lchantel/pv_proj/"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wildboar-mysql-service
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - name: mysql
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      protocol: TCP
  clusterIP: None

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wildboar-mysql-deploy
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: wildboar-mysql-pod
          image: wildboar.mysql:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysqldb-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql/
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: root
          imagePullPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: mysqldb-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pv-claim-mysql
```

Google doesn't help and simply don't know what should i do and where shoud i start from.

Comment: Is there initialized data in `/home/lchantel/pv_proj/`, on every single node in the cluster?  How does it get there?  Whatever's in that host directory on whichever node the pod happens to run on will hide whatever's in `/var/lib/mysql` in the image.  (The standard Docker Hub database images will initialize a new database if the data directory happens to be empty.)

Comment: @David Maze thanks for reply. On /home/lchantel/pv_proj there is no data at all. Actually I thought, that pv-pvc-deploy link contains of /var/lib/mysql directory to my host directory /home/lchantel/pv-proj. So the actual behavior is totally opposite the one I describe above?

Comment: "i guess problem is in yaml file in mountPath section" - Does it work when you don't mount the PV? are there any files in `/var/lib/mysql` baked into container?

Comment: @Matt Actually yeah it works. I've just checked it out...

Comment: Well i guess i can try next solution: not to use /var/lib/mysql/ directory, but new one - /mnt/mysql-data/ as a mountVolume, after that i just copy my data to that directory and change default mysql directory and socket to work with further. But i'll try it tommorow.

Comment: Can you provide a complete solution describing how you solved it? It may benefit some people. Thanks

Comment: Sup, I’ll write solution today. I did not forget about promise, but I simply have no time(

Answer (score 1):

Well, i solved my problem next way

1. I totally remade my mysql Dockerfile. The way alpine wiki suggest to configure mariadb is complicate and doesn't work. `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql/` command was pretty usefull for persisting data in thata directory.
2. I decided to turn .sh to mysql script. And, as far as I manage to use my database for Wordpress there is no reason to create several users in mysql database. It's enough to create one admin. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk upgrade -a -U
RUN apk add mysql mysql-client openrc supervisor
COPY ./mariadb-server.cnf /etc/my.cnf
RUN chmod 755 /etc/my.cnf 
RUN mkdir /sql_data
COPY ./wpdb.sql /sql_data
COPY ./launch.sh /
RUN chmod 755 ./launch.sh
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /sql_data
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql/
RUN mkdir -p /run/mysqld/
EXPOSE 3306
CMD /launch.sh
```

and sql script

```
CREATE DATABASE wordpress;
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'admin'@'%' = PASSWORD('admin');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

3. Superviror service is usefull when you run 2 and more services (supervisord excluded) in the same time. So it's enough to use script with myslq setup and launching it as daemon:

```
#!/bin/sh

mysql_install_db --skip-test-db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
mysqld --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --init-file=/sql_data/wpdb.sql
```

4. There's some little changes in yaml file. We created admin is mysql script, so there is no need to create it in yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - name: mysql
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-mysql
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysqldb-storage
              mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql/"
          imagePullPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: mysqldb-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pv-claim-mysql
```

5. There are some changes in my.cnf configuration file.

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
user=root
port=3306
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
skip-networking=false
socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
wait_timeout = 600
max_allowed_packet = 64M
# Galera-related settings
#[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
# Disabling symbolic links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]
```